# Change Text Colour When Hovering Over Another Element on the Same Level

Tags: html, css

I am trying to change the text colour of `.foo` when the user hovers over `.bar` and I am unsure how to do this with only CSS. I have tried using the CSS preceding element selector `~` but that did not work.

http://jsfiddle.net/847E2/

```
<div>
  <p class="foo">Foo</p>
  <ul class="bar"><li>Bar<li></ul>
</div>

.bar:hover~.foo {
    color: red;
}
```

EDIT - My requirements have changed. I updated my HTML structure to make the `.bar` a `<ul>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sibling selector `~` doesn't select elements preceding it, just elements succeeding it. Thus, when hovering over the element `.bar`, the element `.foo` cannot be selected, as it is preceding `.bar`.

You could do something like this instead:

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/8KxzN/)

```
div:hover :not(:hover) {
    color: red;
}
```

Basically, this is setting the color of the child elements to `color:red` when hovering over the parent, `div`. However, it will not be applied on `:hover` of the element you are on. This makes it seem as though the color is changing when you hover over the sibling element.

Comment: That makes sense. What happens if I modified my HTML structure to where my 2nd `p` (.bar) is now a `ul` instead of a `p`. How would I modify the CSS to achieve the same effect?

Comment: Might want to note that this is CSS3 and not supported in IE<9.

Comment: @JoshC Yup, like that. Let me try integrating that into my code :)

Answer (score 0):

The + selector is an adjacent sibling combinator selector allows you to select an element that is directly after another specific element.

It doesn't matter if you use any element if have .bar class name.

NOTE: There is no "previous sibling" selector, that's why i change the elements order in the DOM.

```
.bar:hover + .foo {
    color: red;
}
```

Demo http://jsfiddle.net/847E2/11/

Also can see: http://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/

[Is there a "previous sibling" CSS selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817792/css-previous-sibling-selector)

Comment: You're reversing the elements in the DOM and that matters.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do it with CSS (no CSS3 needed):

```
div:hover p{
    color: red;
}
.foo:hover{
    color: black;
}
div:hover p.bar{
    color: black;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/4C7me/2)**